# For $q >1,$ $1$-sparse vectors are not solutions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Let $q > 1$ and let $A$ be an $m \times N$ matrix with $m < N.$ Prove that there exists a $1-$sparse vector which is not a minimizer of the following optimization problem:
$$\min_{\textbf{z} \in \mathbb{R}^n} \| \textbf{z} \|_{q}~\textrm{such that}~A\textbf{z}=\textbf{y}.$$

Everything in their usual notations. Any help in solving this is much appreciated.

Comment: what is 1-sparse?

Comment: @LinAlg, vector has at most one zero.

Comment: Is $N>1$? Do you only consider feasible 1-sparse vectors? The question still does not make much sense to me, can you provide some context?

Comment: @LinAlg, this is from Foucar's book, Exe. 3.1 (page 90).

Comment: I don't know what book you mean, and it would be helpful if you post information here instead of referring to a book.

Comment: @LinAlg, my bad. I didn't send the link. http://human-robot.sysu.edu.cn/ebook/preprint093.pdf

And, Yes, N > 1 and they are feasible 1-sparse vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the question ambiguous. You can easily find a $1$-sparse vector that does not satisfy $Az=y$. Then indeed there exists a $1$-sparse vector that is not a minimizer. The requirement $m<N$ is not necessary to prove the statement.

However, I do not think that is what the author intended to ask. This question is introduced on page 62:

> For q > 1, even 1-sparse vectors are not solutions of ($P_q$)—see Exercise 3.1

I do not see why this statement is valid. The book defines $1$-sparse as vectors having at most one nonzero component (p. 3). Consider the problem $$\min_{z \in \mathbb{R}^2} \{ ||z||_q : z_1 = 0 \}$$
Note that $A = [1 \; 0]$, which is an $m \times N$ matrix with $m=1$ and $N=2$, so indeed $m<N$. The unique minimizer is $z = [0, 0]$, which is $1$-sparse.

Comment: I see. I wish this book had examples. I haven't had an optimization class before. I'm studying this book for compressive sensing. Thank you.

Comment: Optimization-wise, it's important to note that the problem is *strictly convex*. That means that when two $1$-sparse vectors are equally good, that the average between those two (which is probably $2$-sparse unless the same component is nonzero) is better than either of them.

Comment: You can find a proof of this result in the lecture notes by Foucart here: http://www.math.tamu.edu/~foucart/teaching/notes/CS.pdf , Lemma 4.2.